# Как построить виджет sparklinebullet в widgetcolumn на основе данных из базы

Tags: extjs

Есть 3 значения в store , как используя их построить sparklinebullet ? Я не понимаю как передать ему массивом эти три значения, вот пример - мне нужен виджет из столбца Bullet https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#widget-grid - но тут используется 'Ext.data.ArrayStore' а у меня обычный Store с тремя полями - 'count', 'total', 'target'

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, на самом деле всё оказалось очень просто, при генерации данных - эти три параметра надо добавить в массив - и уже ключ этого массива использовать в bind